# Connection LDAP through PHP always pass without username

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, apache2

This is my code

```
GNU nano 4.8                                                                                         index.php
            <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>" method="POST">
                <p>
                    USUARIO: <input type="text" name="usuario" id="usuario"/>
                </p>
                <p>
                    CONTRASEÑA: <input type="password" name="contraseña" id="contraseña"/>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <input type="submit" name="enviar" id="enviar"/>
                </p>
            </form>
        </fieldset>
    </body>
</html>
<?php
// using ldap bind
if(isset($_POST['enviar'])){
    if(isset($_POST['usuario'])){
    $ldaprdn  = $_POST['usuario'].'@domain.local'; // ldap rdn or dn
    }
    if(isset($_POST['contraseña'])){
    $ldappass = $_POST['contraseña'];  // associated password
    }

    // connect to ldap server
    $ldapconn = ldap_connect("ldap://server")
        or die("No es posible conectarse con el servidor.");

    if ($ldapconn) {

        // binding to ldap server
        $ldapbind = ldap_bind($ldapconn, $ldaprdn, $ldappass);

        // verify binding
        if ($ldapbind) {
            echo "Conexión correcta.";
        } else {
            echo "<fieldset name='Fallo'>";
                echo "FALLO: Usuario y/o contraseña incorrecta.";
            echo "</fieldset>";
        }

    }
}
?>
```

This code works but when i don´t put any information on the boxes it pass too, with invented users too, only when i put something wrong in the password seems doesn´t work and i can see the else of ldapconn and this message "ldap_bind(): Unable to bind to server: ".

Comment: Your ldap seems to accept anonymous authentication.

Comment: From the documention of `ldap_bind`: `If password is not specified or is empty, an anonymous bind is attempted. `.  See https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-bind

Comment: Site note: `<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>"` can be very unsafe it is possible to do a Cross-site Scripting (XSS) attacks not sure if this is patched in the more modern PHP versions.

Answer (score 0):

@svgta @Tom Regner
Yes it seems that, i don´t know who i didn´t think in put a isset function in the password, now my code is like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['enviar'])){
        if((empty($_POST['usuario']))||(empty($_POST['contraseña']))){

                echo "<fieldset>";
                echo "<b>Por favor introduce el usuario y/o la contraseña</b>";
                echo "</fieldset>";

        }else{

                $ldaprdn  = $_POST['usuario']; // ldap rdn or dn
                $ldappass = $_POST['contraseña'];  // associated password


                // connect to ldap server
                $ldapconn = ldap_connect("ldap://server")
                or die("No es posible conectarse con el servidor.");

                if ($ldapconn) {

                        // binding to ldap server
                        $ldapbind = ldap_bind($ldapconn, $ldaprdn, $ldappass);

                        // verify binding
                                if ($ldapbind) {
                                      
                                } else {
                                        echo "<fieldset name='Fallo'>";
                                        echo "<b>FALLO: Usuario y/o contraseña incorrecta.</b>";
                                        echo "</fieldset>";
                                }
                }
        }
}
```

@Raymond Nijland I didn´t know about that, thanks, now i´m investigating how i can resolve.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).